# basic operand >> not recognized in c++ code after having changed .cpp to .cu

Tags: c++, string

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what's happening in my code. Any help would be much appreciated. Here's my header (.cuh) :

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "SINS_constants.cuh"

using namespace std;

class SINS_inputManager
{
    public:
        static SINS_inputManager& getInstance()
        {
            static SINS_inputManager SINS_inputManager_singleton;
            return SINS_inputManager_singleton;
        }
        void parse(ifstream& cfgfile); // TODO Better read incoming variables, recognize by type in a single loop : template ?

    private:
        static SINS_inputManager* SINS_inputManager_singleton;
        map<string, string> options;

        SINS_inputManager();
        ~SINS_inputManager();
        SINS_inputManager(SINS_inputManager const&);    // not defined copy constructor
        void operator=(SINS_inputManager const&);       // not defined = operator


};
```

Here's my .cu :

```
#include "SINS_inputManager.cuh"

void SINS_inputManager::parse(ifstream& cfgfile)
{
    cout << "\n";

    string id, eq, val;
    while(cfgfile >> id >> eq >> val)
    {
        if (id[0] == '#')
        {
            cfgfile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // skip comments
            continue;
        }

        if (eq != "=") throw runtime_error("Syntax error in the parser. Each line should follow :\n'unique parameter name' = 'value'\nA commented line begins with a '#' symbol.\n\n");

        options[id] = val;
    }

    istringstream theStream;
    string string_temp;

    theStream.clear();
    theStream.str(options["INITIAL_INPUT"]);
    theStream >> string_temp;
    strcpy(INITIAL_INPUT, string_temp.c_str());

    theStream.clear();
    theStream.str(options["FINAL_OUTPUT"]);
    theStream >> string_temp;
    strcpy(FINAL_OUTPUT, string_temp.c_str());

    theStream.clear();
    theStream.str(options["NB_IONS"]);
    theStream >> NB_IONS;

    theStream.clear();
    theStream.str(options["VERBOSE"]);
    theStream >> VERBOSE;

    theStream.clear();
    theStream.str(options["TIME_MAX"]);
    theStream >> TIME_MAX;

    theStream.clear();
    theStream.str(options["DT_OBS"]);
    theStream >> DT_OBS;

    if(VERBOSE >= 1)
    {
        cout << "The parser has read the following configuration :\n";
        typedef map<string, string>::iterator it_type;
        for(it_type iterator = options.begin(); iterator != options.end(); iterator++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << iterator->first << " = " << iterator->second << "\n";
        }
    }
}

// private constructor
SINS_inputManager::SINS_inputManager()
{

}

// private destructor
SINS_inputManager::~SINS_inputManager()
{

}
```

And here's the error :

```
/data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(8): error: no operator ">>" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::ifstream >> std::string

/data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(12): error: incomplete type is not allowed

/data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(12): error: identifier "numeric_limits" is undefined

/data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(12): error: type name is not allowed

/data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(12): error: no instance of overloaded function "max" matches the argument list

/data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(16): error: identifier "runtime_error" is undefined

/data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(21): error: incomplete type is not allowed

7 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000076aa_00000000-6_SINS_inputManager.cpp1.ii".
CMake Error at SINS_generated_SINS_inputManager.cu.o.cmake:256 (message):
  Error generating file
  /data/pieges/fabian/SINS/workdir/CMakeFiles/SINS.dir/code/src/./SINS_generated_SINS_inputManager.cu.o


make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SINS.dir/code/src/./SINS_generated_SINS_inputManager.cu.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SINS.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

Before changing the filename to CUDA extensions, it was working nicely. I searched google and found that it could be an issue with string or string.h include, but I tried all the combination I could without success. What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT : Here's the new output after adding the includes and using namespace std in the .cu :

> Sorry, not exactly the same error (only for the string) :
>
> ```
> /data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(14): error: no operator ">>" matches these operands
>             operand types are: std::ifstream >> std::string
>
> /data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(18): error: incomplete type is not allowed
>
> /data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(18): error: identifier "numeric_limits" is undefined
>
> /data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(18): error: type name is not allowed
>
> /data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(18): error: no instance of overloaded function "max" matches the argument list
>
> /data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(22): error: identifier "runtime_error" is undefined
>
> /data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(27): error: incomplete type is not allowed
>
> 7 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000077e5_00000000-6_SINS_inputManager.cpp1.ii".
> CMake Error at SINS_generated_SINS_inputManager.cu.o.cmake:256 (message):
>   Error generating file
>   /data/pieges/fabian/SINS/workdir/CMakeFiles/SINS.dir/code/src/./SINS_generated_SINS_inputManager.cu.o
>
>
> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SINS.dir/code/src/./SINS_generated_SINS_inputManager.cu.o]
> ```
>
> Erreur 1
>       make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SINS.dir/all] Erreur 2
>       make: *** [all] Erreur 2

Comment: It's not that the operator isn't recognized - it is that it is not defined for the operands used: `std::ifstream` and `std::string`. I think you are right that there is an issue with the header files you are using, but I can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: There is not much CUDA in this question, apart from a `.cu` extension...

Comment: You're right, but since it began to generate error messages when I switch to CUDA extension, I figured out that maybe there's a conflict with a CUDA overload with something related to string or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add next headers to .cu file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks :) I still have this problem though :

/data/pieges/fabian/SINS/code/src/SINS_inputManager.cu(28): error: incomplete type is not allowed

it concerns the line :
std::istringstream theStream;

Comment: add `#include <sstream>`. You can find more information about C++ standart library here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's really appreciated :) I haven't learned C++ in school so this kind of basic reference will be of help !

Answer (score 0):

try to move these lines from .cuh into the .cu file

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

especially this line `using namespace std;`.

Comment: I copied the line you pointed out (can't move them since I require them in the header) and I still have the same errors.
EDIT:
Not exactly the same error.

Comment: use `using namespace std;` in global space of the header is not safe. Try not use it and use `std::map<std::string, std::string>` instead

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will update my daily practice - the problem is still there though